# Local "restful" service

Tags: linux

I have a thermostat which polls a serial interface for the temperature. This interface can't be polled more often than thirty seconds at a time. There are several different python scripts which need access to the temperature which run independent of each other (eg pyramid, celery tasks). None of these scripts are smart enough to avoid overloading the sensor. Thus, implementation options follow:

1. Have a local web restful service that can be polled by any system script and provides the best requisite temperature, but doesn't poll the actual sensor too often behind the scenes (this strikes me as overkill but with ideal features)
2. Store the temperature in an in memory database and have a script update the stored temperature every thirty seconds (this is also heavy weight option to get just one integer)
3. Write a one shot script that handles all of the logic and exits (requires an external file to store when the last sensor poll happened. Not much better than #2 and may wear out an rpi SD card with unnecessary writes)
4. Is there some built in, lightweight Linux feature that is an alternative to #1 (eg dmesg w/ cron)?

Comment: create a file in /var/run with the temperature. /var/run nowadays is memory based...

Comment: Thanks, that should work. Is there no service oriented option for Unix/Linux?

Comment: Did not understood you...could you clarify it?

Comment: Your proposal is the best. I'll mark this solved.

Comment: As for using the raspberry, I have a lamobo R1 with an SSD disk, and I am eying a banana pro or similar that comes with an internal disk because as you correctly point out, MicroSD cards are not very fond of regular I/O.

Comment: (thanks for the points. Often the simpler solutions are the best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a file with some values to share in /var/run; the strategy is used by several services/daemons. You might want to create a subdirectory in /var/run upon boot time, maybe /var/run/temperature if you need to chown it to a non-root user.

The alternative to store it in memory, would be using `redis`, however it is overkill.

There is also the alternative of developing a C program using shared memory, however the need seems to be too simple for that.